# Growing and shrinking table views with auto-layout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autolayout, nstableview

I am trying to build a view that holds several table views stacked vertically. Rather than assign each table view a fixed height, I want the tables to grow with their content. The stack is then nested in a scrollview.

Using auto-layout, I managed to get the nested scroll views grow with their table views. I however cannot get these to shrink as I remove rows from the table view. Auto-layout seems to assume that the best size for a view is its current size. In my set-up the best size would be the smallest fitting size.

The set-up in Interface builder:

```
- Scrollview
-- Clipview
--- Container
---- Nested Scrollview
------ Clipview
------- Tableview
---- Nested Scrollview
------ Clipview
------- Tableview
```

In code I add constraints to pin the leading, trailing, top and bottom of the table views to their immediate parent clip views.

The test project ( https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2381634/SO/AdjacentTableViews%20Auto-Layout.zip ) has buttons to add and remove rows from the two table views.

Adding rows grows the table views, the clip views,…. The outer scull view can scroll as expected.

Removing rows fails to shrink the nested scroll views.

How can I have auto-layout consider the minimum fitting size, hug content, … ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up subclassing NSScrollView and NSTableView to compute intrinsicContentSize in function of the number of lines in the table view:

```
@implementation HHNestedScrollView

- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    NSView  *documentView   = [self documentView];
    NSSize  fSize           = [documentView intrinsicContentSize];

    if (fSize.height >= 0) {
        if (self.borderType != NSNoBorder) {
            fSize.height += 2;
        }
    }

    return fSize;
}

- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [[self nextResponder] scrollWheel:theEvent];

    [self setNeedsLayout:YES];
}

@end


@implementation HHNestedTableView 

- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    NSSize      fSize   = [super intrinsicContentSize];

    NSInteger   nr      = [self numberOfRows];
    CGFloat     rh      = [self rowHeight];
    CGFloat     ih      = [self intercellSpacing].height;

    fSize.height = rh * nr + ih * MAX(nr, 1);

    return fSize;
}

@end
```

My view controller invalidates intrinsicContentSize whenever the number of rows in the table view changes:

```
[[self.tableView enclosingScrollView] invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the inner scroll view to never scroll. They should always be sized to fit the entire contents of the enclosed table view. Right? In that case, I would remove them from the hierarchy. In IB, you can't drag a new table view into the document without a scroll view, but you can drag to copy a table view into another view without the enclosing scroll view.

Comment: Indeed: I want the inner scrollview to never scroll. I had tried many different solutions. The above is what I settled on. Unfortunately I cannot remember all possible solutions or why I ruled them out.

Comment: I do remember some things – probably IB – making the assumption that a table view is tied to a scroll view. I had successfully removed the nested scroll view by editing the XIB XML. The document was valid and worked to some extend, but not well enough.